# Big O - arithmetic rules

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

I need to prove the following statement:
$O(f(n)g(n))=f(n)O(g(n))$
At first I thought the statement is false but apparently it is true. How can I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you want to show is that if $h\in \mathcal O(g)$ then $\tilde h$ defined by
$$\tilde h(n) = f(n)\cdot h(n)$$
is an element of $\mathcal O(fg)$.
The converse needs a case distinction for $f(n) \ne0$ and $f(n) = 0$ to go through.

Comment: $h∈O(g)$ means that $there$  $exists$ $c>0$ and $n_0 in N$ s.t. for all $n > n_0$ we have $|h(n)|<=c|g(n)|$


can I now just multiply both sides by $|f(n)|$ and say that $h~(n))$ belongs to $O(fg)$?

Comment: @rollerboller I know the definition, but you should fix your MathJax there. Use `\leq` for $\leq$ and `\forall` $\forall$...
Regarding the proof, almost. You can do this to get $\tilde h\in \mathcal O(fg)$, not $h\in\mathcal O(fg)$

Comment: I'm working on it. OK, I see your point.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation has a few useful pointers regarding MathJax; For the question, see my edited comment. It is okay, but the result is a tad (but important) bit different.

Comment: It's more than 5mins so I cannot my previous comment. So what I should do instead?

Comment: Well you already got it there:
$$|\tilde h(n)| = |f(n)||h(n)| \le C |f(n)||g(n)|$$
For the converse you do a little more so you may divide by $Cf$ where necessary.

Comment: In this kind of question, do I need to show the equality of sets? I'm a little bit confused with the Big O notation. E.g. here I don't know if it is meant that $O(f(n)g(n))$ is in $f(n)O(g(n))$ or that both sets are equal. If the first is the case, then why I need to prove the converse of the statement?

Comment: @rollerboller $\mathcal O(f)$ is a set, $f\mathcal O(g)$ is the set obtained by element-wise multiplication of the elements of $\mathcal O(g)$ with $f$.